# How to prove that application source code correspond to specified snapshot at runtime?

Tags: security, formal-verification, trust

Say, I want to use some application. It uses some sensitive information. I don't want to blindly trust this application. There are sources available, though. So, I can review it, and decide to trust it, or refuse to do so.

Is there a way to prove that application deployed somewhere (possibly in an untrusted environment such as someone's private server) has been done so from exactly source code snapshot that I reviewed? At runtime. Some sort of application self-reporting that couldn't be tampered with. Maybe, some formal approach?

I'm interested in this from developer point of view. Can I do so, encouraging users to not trust me, but rather to verify?

For example, as a developer, I can assure that an application doesn't persist any data - only in-memory processing, then data will disappear forever. Can that be proved?

Comment: I'm not aware of any system that can guarantee this. But open-source-software is one way to get there: You publish the sources and the user "compiles" it themselves. Of course, this doesn't address the deployment part of the question, which makes it interesting. Even if a cryptographic hash can be used to sign the binary, I'm not aware of any method that can ensure the sources were the same. Just think about compiler optimizations: Would you consider the binary the "same" if compiled using different sets of compiler flags? To get a good answer, you'll need to be much more specific.